# Join two object arrays with google map coordinates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two object arrays that have similar values but I cannot figure out how to merge them.

```
var Cars = [{
    lat: 42,
    lng: -72
}, {
    lat: 40.7127837,
    lng: -74.0059413
}, {
    lat: 40.735657,
    lng: -74.1723667
}];

var Trucks = [{
    lat: 43,
    lng: -72.5
}, {
    lat: 40.612837,
    lng: -74.1239413
}, {
    lat: 40.564657,
    lng: -74.1803667
}];
```

I have tried the code below but all I get in the console is a bunch of objects no values.

```
var Vehicles = Cars.concat(Trucks);

for (var i = 0; i < Vehicles.length; i++)
{
    console.log(Vehicles[i]);
}
```

Comment: What's the end goal?

Comment: Use it with fitBounds from the Google Maps V3 API to see all the markers.

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you try logging `JSON.stringify(Vehicles[i])` to see if you are confused with the way its shown in console?

Comment: your code works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(Cars, Trucks)
```

EDIT: Explanation

Both `Cars` and `Trucks` are `array`s. The `push` function on the `Array` prototype receives as many parameters as you want and pushes each of them into an array. For example:

```
var a = [1,2];
a.push(3,4,5);
console.log(a); // => [1,2,3,4,5]
```

When calling `apply` on *any* function, you specify two things: the value of the `this` variable within the function, and an array containing the list of parameters being passed on the function. Therefore calling

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(a, [3,4,5])
```

will call the `push` function on the `a` array, by passing it three parameters: `3`, `4` and `5`.

EDIT 2: Please note that doing this will **overwrite** the original array (the one being pass as the first parameter to the `apply` function call).